# Azure - Centralized management of client secrets

Tags: azure, azureportal

You can easily create a client id and secret for each app registration under certificates and secrets. Is there a way to be able to use the same client id and secret for all apps in the subscription and manage them centrally? Through management groups maybe? If so, do you need a special licensing agreement to do so?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to be able to use the same client id and secret for all
> apps in the subscription and manage them centrally?

AFAIK, it is not possible as both client id and secret are auto-generated when they are created. Azure does not allow you to specify values for client id and secret.

Comment: I don't mind if they're auto-generated, I'm just wondering if there's a way to use the same id and secret for each app registration in the subscription. Like create an id and secret once and then associate it with multiple app registrations

Comment: Considering the id and secret are auto-generated, I am not sure how you can use the same id and secret. One possible way would be to use just one app registration with all the necessary permissions and use that.

Comment: is it autogenerated each time it is used? You can't just have it auto-generated once and then use it for multiple apps?

Comment: As mentioned in my answer, the id and secret are automatically assigned when they’re created. They’re not regenerated  every time they’re used.

Answer (score 0):

you don't any control over client secret ,it's auto generated